# marginal notes in both margins depending on the page number

Tags: double-sided, marginpar

The lines of my text are numbered because I'm producing an edition with notes in the bottom. I'd like to have marginal notes as well on the left for even page numbers and on the right for un even page numbers. Is that possible, without interfering with the line numbering?

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{parskip}
\textheight = 180.5 mm
\textwidth = 108.5 mm
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{microtype}
\hyphenation{Maies-ties}
```

Comment: Which class are you using? In book class, the default is to use different places for margin notes, according to the page numbers.

Comment: Are you selecting "twosided"? (I thought the behavior you request is the default for two sided documents)

Comment: For the time being I'm usng \ledsidenote{} commands.

Comment: should I use \marginpar{} commands instead?

Comment: Found what I wanted here http://www.djdekker.net/ledmac/examples.html

Comment: @GuillaumeCoatalen Please consider writing that up as an answer so that others can see your solution more easily. (You can answer your own question - that's not a problem.)

Comment: all you need to do is include: \linenummargin{inner}
\sidenotemargin{outer}